# How to calculate thermal noise contributed by an LNA?

Tags: noise, signal-processing, thermal, signal-to-noise

I've written a thermal noise simulation for a piece of equipment which produces the oscilloscope trace one would expect to see coming out of the instrument.

Now, I'd like to take into consideration contributions made by an Amplifier (LNA) which is part of the instrument.

Comment: *the LNA has a noise-figure as well as some front-end gain* Generally LNAs (which are just amplifiers) are described as having a NF and a Gain. "Front end" doesn't mean anything in my opinion, unless the LNA has at least two stages, a front end (again having a NF and Gain) and a back end (or output stage) also having NF and Gain).

Comment: *The noise figure is 1.5, with 60dB of power (translating to 30dB of voltage). The gain is unknown* Uhm you just said there's 60 dB power gain and 30 dB **voltage** gain!? You probably mean "overall gain" of (some part of) the system. In my view, that unknown gain isn't relevant (yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to determine the noise level at the **input of the LNA**.

The LNA has 60 dB Power gain so at the **output** the **signal** has a 60 dB higher power level.

**If** the LNA was noiseless, then the **noise** would also be amplified by 60 dB (same as the signal). However, the LNA isn't noiseless, it has a NF of 1.5 dB that means that it adds 1.5 dB to the noise level. So the noise level at the **input of the LNA** will be amplified by 60 dB + 1.5 dB = 61.5 dB.

Example:

**At input of LNA:**

Signal = **-60 dBm**, noise = **-100 dBm**

S/N ratio = 40 dB

**At output of LNA:**

Signal: Signal level + 60 dB = -60 dBm + 60 dB = **0 dBm**

Noise: Noise level + 60 dB + 1.5 dB = -100 dBm + 61.5 dB = **-38.5 dBm**

S/N ratio = 38.5 dB (1.5 dB worse due to NF = 1.5 dB).