# How to calculate noise voltage after amplification?

Tags: noise, signal, signal-processing, thermal, signal-to-noise

I'm simulating the thermal noise experienced by some instrument, outputted as a voltage vs time plot. To calculate the "power" of this noise, I'm using:

P = 4kTB (k = Boltzmann's constant, T = temperature (Kelvins), and B = bandwidth (MHz))

And I then convert to voltage using:

V^2 / R = 4kTB (R = resistance (Ohms), of course)

I then produce a series of random values, distributed as a Gaussian around a mean given by this voltage, and an RMS given by:

sqrt(4kTBR)

**Now** I'd like to take into account an amplifier that is attached to the instrument. I know the amplifier provides 60dB of gain, and it has a Noise Figure of 5. How do I calculate the resulting change in power and/or voltage?

Comment: I recently answered a very similar question, see: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/519421/how-to-calculate-thermal-noise-contributed-by-an-lna/519427#519427

Answer (score 1):

Noise figure is defined as:
$$NF = 10log_{10}(\frac{SNR_i}{SNR_o})$$
Thus,
$$5 = 10log_{10}(\frac{V_i^2N_o}{V_o^2N_i})$$
$$5 = -20log_{10}(\frac{V_o}{V_i})+10log_{10}(\frac{N_o}{N_i})$$
First term is the gain, so
$$10log_{10}(\frac{N_o}{N_i}) = 5+60 = 65$$
$$10log_{10}(N_o) = 10log_{10}(N_i) + 65 dB$$
$$10log_{10}(N_o) = 10log_{10}(4kTRB) + 65 dB$$
Hopefully, the symbols are self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

Noise Figure of 3dB tells us the Amplifier contributes as much Noise Power as a 50 Ohm resistor, assuming you have a 50 ohm_reference circuit.

At 5dB, the noise power will be larger, as "sarthak" demonstrates.

The point of these 3 paragraph is ---- you will have more than double the power, **IF THE SOURCE IMPEDANCE EQUALS THE AMPLIFIER REFERENCE IMPEDANCE**

Thus RF Design has standardized on 50 ohms as the Reference Impedance.

You need to determine that (Reference Impedance) for your signal source and for your amplifier.